# How to join an UI to the main thread in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, graphics

I have a program with several UIs each one drawing graphics in the same area one after the other. Each change is event-driven.
Now I have to work with an RFID which has to perform connection and some other time-consuming operations along with the possibility of waiting for a tag. Therefore all that stuff has to be done in a Thread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => 
{
    while (err == errNOTAG)
    {
        try
        {
            err = 0;
            byArray = bisvController.ReadTypeAndSerial(RfidPort);               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err = ex.HResult;
        }
    }
    if (byArray != null)
    {
    ... under some conditions proceed <-----
    }   
});
t.Start();
```

So if I go on like this I get the usual error

> The calling thread must be STA because many UI components require this

So now I could do all the graphics with Application.Dispatcher but I don't want to do this for I would have to change a ton of code.

Instead what I want to do is **to re-join to the main thread**.
The solution I have found is to use a timer in the main thread with a condition set in the Thread above with something like that:

```
bool ProceedCondition = false;
Thread t = new Thread(() => 
{
    while (err == errNOTAG)
    {
        try
        {
            err = 0;
            byArray = bisvController.ReadTypeAndSerial(RfidPort);               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err = ex.HResult;
        }
    }
    if (byArray != null)
    {
        ProceedCondition = true;
    }   
});
t.Start();
```

and then the time checking for ProceedCondition and when set to true continuing to the next UI. So this works for the timer is defined in the main thread. Can anyone suggest another solution for **re-joining to the main thread**?

Thanks in advance

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Typically you do something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => {
    /* code you want to run on the GUI thread goes here */
}));
```

If you need to wait for the operation to complete then Wait on the task, or do an await if you're already in a task to begin with:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => {
        /* code you want to run on the GUI thread goes here */
})).Wait();
```

Comment: I might have misunderstood the meaning of your answer but if I put something very simple like that Task.Run(async () => await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new System.Action(() => 
{ Console.WriteLine("BBBB");}))).Wait(); the system just hangs. Am I missing something?

Comment: "If you need to wait for the operation to complete" do not call `BeginInvoke` but just `Invoke`.

Comment: @Patrick that would imply that your main thread is probably blocking something else e.g. whatever task you're calling this from. Can't diagnose it without seeing your other code but you'll need to remove that block if you want to switch back to the GUI thread.

Comment: @MarkFeldman you are right!! The blocking line is     Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => {  lbxWatch.Items.Clear(); });   but why?!?!?

Comment: @Clemens could you please provide me with an example? When changing BeginInvoke --> Invoke I get an error "cannot convert lambda expression to delegate". I searched for a solution but Google is not my friend

Comment: @Patrick As shown in the answer: `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { ... }));`